# Find Var(Y|X=x).

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, variance

The joint probability density function of X and Y is f(x,y) = 2/3 for 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 2, x < y, and 0 otherwise. I am trying to use the formula Var(Y|X) = E(Y^2|X)-(E(Y|X))^2. I have already calculated E(Y|X) to be (2+x)/2. But I'm unsure how to get f(Y^2) in order to find E(Y^2|X). Any tips please?

Comment: Please show your work for $E(Y|X)$. It follows the same procedure, but with $Y^2$ when integrating.

Comment: f(x) = 4/3-2/3x. then f(Y|X) = f(x,y)/f(x) = (2/3)/(4/3-2/3x)= 1/2-x. E(Y|X=x) is integrating y(1/2-x) over x to 2 w.r.t y. and I eventually arrive at 2+x/2

Answer (score 1):

$E[Y|X] = \frac {\frac 23\int_x^2 y\ dy}{\frac 23\int_x^2 \ dy} = \frac {\frac 12(4-x^2)}{2-x} = \frac 12(2+x)$

$E[Y^2|X] = \frac {\frac 23 \int_x^2 y^2\ dy}{\frac 23\int_x^2 \ dy} = \frac {\frac 13(2^3-x^3)}{2-x} = \frac 13(4+2x+x)$

$E[Y^2|X] - (E[Y|X])^2 = \frac  13(4 + 2x + x^2) - \frac 14(4 + 4x + x^2) = \frac {1}{12} (4 -4x + x^2)$

Comment: I see the method thank you. i think though there is a typo in the last line, expansion of (2+x)^2 should be (4+4x+x^2)

Comment: @susan thanks....